# ImportError: No module named pyplot - Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, threshold

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Paw01.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
      'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]
for i in xrange(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()`
```

**But, It returns the error:**

> **Traceback (most recent call last):**   File "/home/lrcorre/Desktop/Paper
>   SIBGRAPI/OpenCV_Programs/Thresholding.py", line 3, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "/home/lrcorre/Desktop/Paper SIBGRAPI/OpenCV_Programs/matplotlib.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   **ImportError:** No module named pyplot

I already installed `matplotlib`, `Opencv` and `python 2.7`.
Anyone know how can I fix this problem and proceed?

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib is python plotting library directory name. Under that directory there is a file pylot.py like this.

```
/dir1/dir2/.../site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py
```

In your case you have matplotlib.py defined somewhere along your PYTHONPATH directory.

```
 /home/lrcorre/Desktop/PaperSIBGRAPI/OpenCV_Programs/matplotlib.py
```

This prohibits importing the pyplot.py file you want. So change the file name to something different.

Comment: Tks for the answer! It runs now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use python 2.7 version:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)  # parentheses necessary in python 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you are importing the module in, is not named matplotlib.py. It solved the problem for me.